# How to name the blank value in select?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, simple-form

I use simple_form in my app.

How do i give the blank value in my selects a different text than "" ?

I just find an option to include blank or not.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It depends on how you are constructing your options for select.  If you're doing it like the code below, just pass a string into the :include blank.

```
select("post", "person_id", Person.all.collect {|p| [ p.name, p.id ] }, {:include_blank => 'Some text here'})
```

If you're setting the options with a options_for_select(), then you can do something like the following:

```
options_for_select([["Dollar", "$"], ["Kroner", "DKK"]])
```

With the value="" being the second value in the array and the name that shows up in the dropdown being first.  So in your case, you could change the second answer to look like this:

```
options_for_select([["Some text here", ""], ["Dollar", "$"], ["Kroner", "DKK"]])
```

Comment: This wasn't asked, but if you want the blank option not to be selectable you can add `:include_blank => true, disabled: "", selected: "", placeholder: "Foo Bar"`

Comment: Georgi has a better answer, below. instead of `include_blank`, use `prompt: 'Which person?' `  It will have a blank value, but the display text you provide. `include_blank` only accepts a boolean -- it does not accept a string to display.

Answer (score 37):

Instead of

```
:include_blank => true
```

Try

```
:include_blank => "your text here"
```

if this is what you are looking.

Comment: Although not the answer to the question - it was the answer to my question as I wanted to set the blank label - cheers.

Comment: This will not work for `select_tag` methods but will work with `select` methods. (And, yes, they _are_ different.) Using a string for the value in the `include_blank` will only provide a blank option with no string. Use `prompt` in that case.

Answer (score 23):

If you are using the `select_tag(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})` function, the correct option is `:prompt => "Some text"` rather than setting a string value for `select`

Comment: Took me too long to figure out it is different for select_tag than a traditional select. Thanks.

Comment: tag behaves so much differently all over the place. trips me up all the time, as well.

Comment: This is absolutely correct and a bit tricky to understand. `select_tag` **will** accept a `include_blank` option but it will NOT display the text you pass as in as the value for that option. You need to use `prompt` for that. Thanks @Georgi!

Comment: Rails 6.1 prompt is working on select and not just select_tag.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this manually by adding `["Your Text", ""]` to the beginning of the array passed to `options_for_select`, or add `"<option value=\"\">#{h("Your Text"}</option>"` to beginning of the string passed to `select_tag`.